# Lua 4.0.1 appendto

Tags: io, lua

Could someone please explain the proper way to use the appendto function?

I am trying to use it to write debug text to a file. I want it written immediately when I call the function, but for some reason the program waits until it exits, and then writes everything at once.

Am I using the right function? Do I need to open, then write, then close the file each time I write to it instead?

Thanks.

Comment: appendto, write, flush, write, flush,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are having an issue with buffering (this also a common question in other languages, btw). The data you want to write to the file is being held in a memory buffer and is only being written to disk in a latter time (this is done to batch writes to disk together, for better performance).

One possibility is to open and close the file as you already suggested. Closing a file handle will flush the contents of the buffer to disk.

A second possibility is to use the `flush` function to explicitly request that the data be written to disk. In Lua 4.0.1, you can either call flush passing  a file handle

```
-- If you have opened your file with open:
local myfile = open("myfile.txt", "a")
flush(myfile)

-- If you used appendto the output file handle is in the _OUTPUT global variable
appendto("myfile.txt")
flush(_OUTPUT)
```

or you can call flush with no arguments, in which case it will flush all the files you have currently open.

```
flush()
```

For details, see the reference manual: http://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/manual.html#6.